# NL (Dutch) locale in Swing does not seem to work

Tags: java, swing, locale

I have a java application with multi-language support. When I change the language (in a preferences dialog), the language of the entire application changes, including the language of Swing components like `JFileChooser`. That is working perfect for English, Spanish and French. But when I choose Dutch, the language of Swing components (`JFileChooser`, confirm dialogs, etc.) changes to English.

Below is the code that changes the language to Dutch. Remark: for the other languages I use the same code (except for the `"NL"` string, of course) and it works fine.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("nl");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
JComponent.setDefaultLocale(locale);
```

I also tried creating the locale using `new Locale("nl", "BE");` and `new Locale("nl", "NL");` but none of them worked. Is there a problem with the Dutch locale? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Could it be that the locale isn't available on your system, so it falls back to default?

Comment: A quick check says the language code should be lower case so `Locale locale = new Locale("nl");` or `new Locale("nl", "NL");` but I doubt that is it.

Comment: I'm using new Locale("nl"); I made a mistake in the post. I'll update it. thanks @Sign

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html) Dutch is not supported for User Interface Translations:

User Interface Translation
Java SE Runtime Environment
The user interface elements provided by the Java SE Runtime Environment 6, include Swing dialogs, messages written by the runtime environment to the standard output and standard error streams, as well as messages produced by the tools provided with the JRE. These user interface elements are localized into the following languages:

Language Locale ID
Chinese (Simplified) zh_CN 
Chinese (Traditional) zh_TW 
English en 
French fr 
German de 
Italian it 
Japanese ja 
Korean ko 
Portuguese (Brazilian) pt_BR 
Spanish es 
Swedish sv

Answer (score 8):

Some years to late... But you can also create a wrapper class like this

```
public class DutchLocale {
    static public final Locale NL = new Locale("nl", "NL");
}
```